# What is the scope of a variable declared in a switch statement scope?

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't compile as `const bar` is already declared.

I wouldn't have expected this to be the case due to the scoping of the switch statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const barReducer = (state, { event, payload }) => {
  var bars = state.bars
  switch (event) {
    case 'insert':
      const bar = parseBar(payload)
      bars[bar.timestamp] = bar
      return { ...state, bars: bars }
    case 'update':
      const bar = parseBar(payload)
      bars[bar.timestamp] = bar
      return { ...state, bars: bars }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: `const` is block scoped. The closest block starts at `switch (event) {`.

Comment: `const` has *block* scope. `case` isn't a block delimiter…

Comment: Changing it to `case '': { ... }` will resolve the syntax error